# Different developer accounts for same company on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

We have a problem.
I searched all over Stack Overflow but couldn't found the right answer.

First I want to tell, that we are not company that is working on projects for others (outsourcing), but we are company that is working on our project but in two completely different categories.

We found problems when we tried to open another developer account with our company, so we can sell apps with under different accounts on App Store. 
App store rejected us, saying we can only have one developer account connected with our company.

This would not be problem for us, if we could change developer displayed name on app store, so users could not see our "different category" apps connected under "more apps by this developer".

I read it somewhere, that if we use different Provisioning profile for each app, apps will not be connected on app store??

Is there any other option to release app under different developer name on App Store, or we really have to open another company just because we don't want our apps to be connected on App Store?

We don't have same problems with Google Play, but I know that these two stores have different "selling models"...

Comment: A company developer agreement is linked to the legal entity; the company. In order to have a different developer agreement you will need a different legal entity (with its own DUNS number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, Apple doesn't allow a single legal entity (your company) to have multiple accounts on the App Store. You probably want to really think about why you'd need multiple accounts. If there is a plausible reason, there might be reason enough to open a new legal entity (another company such as a subsidiary, for example) and this could have its own account.

Comment: Yeah.. So I am right.. If we want another account we need another company.. But what about just not presenting apps under same developer name? "other apps by this developer".. As example, some apps would be from Medical category and others for example from Games.. And you don't want to link those apps so users from Medical wont be confused?

Comment: It's not possible to disable this in iTunes Connect, you would need different accounts.